# Can you assign a EIP to Network Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-nlb

I have an AWS Network Load Balancer associated with a target group of 2 EC2 instances in different availability zones. I want to load balance traffic to both of them.

I want a single EIP in front of NLB so that when I hit the EIP address, the traffic reaches the NLB and is load-balanced across my EC2 instances.

Or ...

Can I place an EC2 in front of NLB having an EIP to which the NLB DNS name resolves?

What are different approaches I can try and what are the pros and cons?

Comment: are there any way to achieve the goal.

Comment: This one did not work but I have achieved the same thing inside the application that will consume the IP. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can attach elastic IPs to internet facing network load balancers. There's a full walkthrough on how to do that here: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-attach-elastic-ip-to-public-nlb